# How to calculate the average of a set of measurements with uncertainties?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

How would one calculate the average for the following measurements:

1.22 +/- 0.05
1.21 +/- 0.05
1.21 +/- 0.05

I understand how to calculate the average of a set of numbers, but I don't know what do with these uncertainty values.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a physics question. This could be a question on the math site. Note, however, that this is discussed in elementary statistics books. Do you have one to check?

Comment: The measurements have equal weights!

Comment: You don't say what the error bars represent. Are they random errors (in which case getting three measurements within 0.01 looks odd)? Or are they an estimate of a possible systematic error?

Comment: Your question already has already been asked here and got a good answer, so I've voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the root law (from statistics), that is the new error is the square root of the sum of the squares of the errors and divide it by 3 (number of measurements). This is analogous to the standard deviation

Comment: This is only true if the data are uncorrelated and the errors represent normally distributed random uncertainties. The OP does not say. It would also not be correct if the data points had unequal error bars.

Answer (score -2):

All you have to do is to find the average of all the primary values (Let it be x).
Then you find the average of the errors given. If it is the same, let it be that number. (Like in this case, it is 0.05) (Let it be d).
The Final Answer is x +/- d.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you have several measurements, the final uncertainty is smaller. But the answer must depend in what those quoted uncertainties represent.

Comment: But if you take the maximum and minimum values, you are supposed to get these values as a range.

Comment: If the uncertainties are "random" errors, the uncertainty in the mean will be (in this case where they are all identical) $0.05/\sqrt{3}$.